# Select a different value in a static dropdown using angular.js

Tags: magento, javascript-framework, angularjs

I have a Magento product page producing static select elements, to which the price mechanism is tied in to backend, so i can't touch those dropdowns. I am using an angular.js radio element to recieve user input, which should in turn update the static dropdown's selected option.

I don't know how to link the two, I have recreated the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/ldn_tech_exec/smBdC/1/

I want the radio button to update the dropdown, but I can only manipulate the dropdown **after it has been created**, perhaps using jquery to insert any angular directives required.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED again: Your select list needs an ng-model and the options should be generated with ng-options. When you select a radio button, the controller method you trigger should update that ng-model, which will cause the select list to update.
See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Another way to do this is to use ng-selected.  See
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSelected

UPDATE #3: I missed the fact that you can't modify the select list initially.  See my fiddle in the comments below for a working solution.

Comment: Thanks Mark. However, I cannot generate the dropdown with ng-options as it is generated by Magento. I had a look at ng-selected, this might be an option if I can inject the directive into the dropdown after DOM load, then get Angular to recognise the changes. Will update soon.

Comment: Checked out ng-selected, unfortunately it will only work for linking checkboxes to a single value dropdown

Comment: See if this does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/HCPku/
I used this trick http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#compile to add the ng-model to the select list in the controller (inside $timeout to wait for the DOM to finish rendering), then in calculateUpgradeSupplement() I looped through the select list to find the matching Tier, then updated the model.  Angular then updated the select list due to the model update.

Comment: Note that in my fiddle the dropdown doesn't update the radio -- does that matter for your application?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some product where the price depends on the options set.

If this is the case then updating the drop-down from your radio button is relatively trivial - or at least depending on your prototype/jquery skills.

However there is a gotcha: once you update the drop-down in javascript with an 'invisible hand' there is a whole lot more javascript code to update the price and availability. To do this you need to bubble the event. This doesn't happen automatically if using prototype.

I hoped I could rustle up the 'bubble code' but I don't currently have it to hand, besides, you aren't stuck at that point, yet...

Comment: I'm not asking about updating it with prototype or jquery. I want to use angular to do the updating, because the selected value is already in the angular model

Comment: Not very clear on what is angular and what is stock Magento on your page, however, there is frontend product.js code to populate those standard drop-downs. You code basically has to run after that so you may want to create the radio buttons in javascript rather than template code.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Magento javascript. Take a look at the js fiddle